# How can I implement a two step login using spring security?

Tags: spring, session, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I have a spring web application which shows a login dialog as its first page. The only provided inputs in the login page are for the username and the password. I want the user to be able to input his/her username and password and then click on the a button which will check if the user is available in an ldap directory. Then I want another input (dropdown) to appear in the same page which will let the user select what page to go to.
The problem is that as far as I understand, once spring security authenticates the user, the page has to ***reload*** so the session cookie is stored in the user's browser and upon reload it is checked with the ones in the application store so the user is known as logged in.

The ***reload*** is my problem. I want the user credentials be checked and if he has enough clearance, then I want to return a list of pages which he can choose from to land on.

Guys please don't ask me to post some code here. If you know what I am talking about, then you don't need the code. Just tell me what to do.

Comment: Is the choice of target pages different for each user or is it the same across the application? If the former, is that really required? Are the target pages really so sensitive that they have to be protected by login? For example, bank and broker websites have a similar functionality but they allow users to choose the target page along with the username and password. What is shown on the chosen page is of course different for each user so there is no loss of confidentiality. Another option would be to open a dashboard page on successful login from where the user can choose the target page.

Comment: I said pages so the problem would appear a little more simple. The user is actually a member of several **projects**. When I know the user is valid and can login, I want to show him the list of available **projects** he can see and he can only see one project at a single time.

Comment: In one of our applications we do exactly this same thing where we have two starting pages. The user profile page is the starting page after login if the user is not allocated to any project. The project dashboard page is the starting page if they are allocated to one or more projects. We allow the user to choose a single project as their default and then they can change to a different project from a dropdown, if required. So far we have not received any negative feedback from any user on this scheme. If the user is allocated to only one project, that is the default any way.

Comment: That is what we are doing it too. We just want to make it easier by doing both the login and project selection on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX to authenticate the user, if the user is authenticated the server returns appropriate HTTP status and may be list of pages which you need to show in drop down this is really your choice how you want to get the list of pages which needs to be shown to the user. Based on the HTTP status code which is returned by the server you can decide whether or not to display the list of pages to the user and this way you page never reloads.

Comment: Your answer is valid but without reloading the page you don't have a session cookie which contains the session id. Without having that, the user cannot access other pages of the application.

Comment: How about adding a custom filter in spring security filter chain, where you can handle such authenticated users manually and allow them to see the requested pages, after this the Authentication will be set in the Security context and you can bypass this filter when Authentication is set. A bit dirty but should work.